# I can't open executable shared on my network

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, samba

I just set up a new Windows 7 machine and I am having accessing files on my network. I had no problem accessing the network shares and browsing through the files, but when I try to actually open an executable it gives me an error about it not being accessible because I don't have permission. Usually when I connect to my network shares for the first time it asks for a username and password, but it didn't this time. I assume this is the problem here. How can I supply my credentials to the network share even though it doesn't ask for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to map it with the net command via a command prompt.

```
net use h: \\[Server Name]\[Share Name] /user:[Logon Server]\[User Name] [Password] /persistent:yes
```

Example:

```
net use h: \\server\share /user:username password
```

or if you don't want to map the drive letter but still provide the credentials.

```
net use \\server\share /user:username password
```

Note: Server can also be the IP address of the server.

Comment: I dont want to map the share as a drive

Comment: You can use net use without putting in a drive letter. Just omit the drive letter and add the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Your username/password used to connect to these shares are also stored under the **Credential Manager**.

You can find it in the Control Panel.